# Mvc api dont access my Value Get function

Tags: api, model-view-controller

Hello and thanks for taking your time to help me.

I have been using this guide, to try learn about api calls with mvc.

But when I Write Localhost:xxxxx/api/values I get the 404 error, and I cant seem to find out why.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace APITEST
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

**Index2.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49866/api/Values",
            //url: '/API/Value',
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("<tr><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#tbPerson");
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) { console.log(msg) }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        PersonEntities db = new PersonEntities();
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            return db.Persons.ToList();
            //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Can someone see why i get the 404 error?

Comment: is there confirmation about this URL localhost:49866???

Comment: did you check the console for  url ??

Comment: I can confirm that when i run my project my localhost is Localhost:49866, As you can see when i run my Home/Index2 and i look in my console it says: http://localhost49866/api/values with the error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you can see there is no **:** in the given url in your comments

Comment: sorry that is just a misstype from my side, it do say localhost:49866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that you `Application_Start()` in your `Global.asax` file contains the following code?

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem but not i just get a 500 internal server error